# How to pass an array to a method and then determine the array's size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this method:

```
+ (NSData *) createWave: (short[])sampleData {
    int i = [sampleData count]; // Warning: Invalid receiver type 'short int *'
}
```

Inside this method, I'm trying to determine how many elements are in the `samples` array that was passed in.  But I'm getting the warning above (I get the same warning if I change `samples` to `short *`).

How can I pass an array like this, and then determine the array's size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Either make sure that the last element in your array is unique and check for that or pass in a size parameter as well i.e.

```
+ (NSData *) createWave:(short [])samples size:(size_t)count {
    int i = count;
}
```

short[] isn't an object so you can't call methods on it - that's why you're getting a warning (and probably a crash if you run the code!)

Comment: You should provide the type to `count`, otherwise it defaults to `id`.

Comment: `+ (NSData *) createWave:(short [])samples size:(size_t)count;`

Comment: Oops, that'll teach me to type quickly! I've typed it as size_t :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a C style array as a parameter and then access it as an Objective-C object. (I am assuming sampleData and samples are supposed to be the same). Use an [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) of `NSNumber`s instead because with C style arrays you need to know the length.

```
+ (NSData *) createWave: (NSArray*)sampleData {
    int i = [sampleData count];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo, thanks. I'm avoiding using `NSArray` here for performance reasons - this is raw audio data, which can be quite large.

Comment: I understand and I gave the other answer +1 for that reason